# maui: buttons at the end of a layout usually dont work

Tags: maui

this is sooo annoying... as always with "new" frameworks; they have their fair share of issues, but in this case this is such a basic funcationality.

In Short, If I have a button inside a grid and it is the last element (in this case the second row) and I did this:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Layout Grid.Row="0">
</Layout>

<Button Margin="0,50,0,50" Grid.Row="1" WidthRequest="180" Text="{x:Static res:Strings.TestBeenden}" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

The button would render at the exact position where it is supposed to, but it wont be clickable.

ONly if I gave the first RowDef a value like so

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The Button is clickable just fine.
But I cant give it a static size - it is just not feasible.

Anyone else having this issue and or maybe found a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I have more info on that; the issue comes from the scrollview when data is populated into it later. It doesnt resize its layout. A workaround is to add an eventhandler to all the child layouts inside the scrollview that potentually could resize due to layout changes (item gets removed or added) and then for a resize on the scrollview:

```
private void VerticalStackLayout_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (scrollView as IView)?.InvalidateMeasure(); // if not done, everything else will fail 
}
```

in XAML:

`<VerticalStackLayout PropertyChanged="VerticalStackLayout_PropertyChanged"` (add this to every layout that is inside the scrollview and could change its content at rumtime)

this in the end works.

So my guess is that the hitbox around the button does not get shifted down while the UI element itself does.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided. I set the click event on the button and it worked well. When I clicked the button the label will change.

Here is the code I tested:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
            <Label x:Name="mylabel" ></Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button Margin="0,50,0,50" Grid.Row="1" WidthRequest="180" Text="estBeenden" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
        
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
int count = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        mylabel.Text = $"{count}";
        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(mylabel.Text);
    }
```

Comment: please see my answer, i have more details about the issue